# Как сделать функцию нажатия с логическим ИЛИ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Только начал изучение jQuery, по этому сталкиваюсь с камнями....

Такой пример:
Имея 3 кнопки:

```
<input type="submit" name="1" value="1" id="1">
<input type="submit" name="2" value="2" id="3">
<input type="submit" name="3" value="3" id="3">
```

Как сделать функцию нажатия с логическим ИЛИ?
То есть Должна быть нажата любая из трех кнопок...
Пробывал так:

```
$('body').on('click', '#1'||'#2'||'#3', function() {
alert('Вы нажали!');
});
```

Не получается.... Как правильно это сделать? или есть другие варианты?)

Comment: Вы начали сталкиваться с камнями по той причине, что начали изучать jQuery, а не JS. Селекторы строкой, через запятую. ID не может начинаться с цифры.

Comment: Мне надо сделать как к примеру условие...
То есть:
if ($odin == 1 || $dva == 2 || $tri == 3) {
Код!
}

Comment: Я вам уже написал выше. К тому же, добавил по поводу ID

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю основы. просто спешил с примером. вы меня же поняли что надо)) но вот в моем примере в этой функции логические операторы не как не использовать?? если мне надо не ИЛИ а И или НЕ)))

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '#id1, #id2, #id3', function() {
    alert('Вы нажали!');
});`

Comment: Я это понял прекрасно. Не дурак. Вопрос про логические операторы в основном блин)))

Comment: В селекторах нет логических операторов.

Comment: По поводу НЕ - есть `:not()` https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Понять бы что вы хотите

Answer (score 0):

> `'#1'||'#2'||'#3'`

Селекторы надо писать внутри строки через запятую: `'#1, #2, #3'`.

Но вообще, скорее всего так делать не надо, а надо подписаться на класс.